# How do I solve level 41?

Tags: think-different

[image]

I can't solve this level in Think Different. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

These two seems to fit the given numbers:

(47+63)/2 = 55

(85+99)/2 = 92

So the answer should be

(73+25)/2 = **49**